# Time series encoder-decoder LSTM in Keras

Tags: keras, time-series, autoencoder, decoder, encoder-decoder

I am using 9 features and 18 time steps in the past to forecast 3 values in the future:

```
lookback = 18
forecast = 3
n_features_X = 9
n_features_Y = 1
```

My code is:

```
# Encoder
past_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(lookback, n_features_X), name='past_inputs')
encoder = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(past_inputs)

# Decoder
future_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(forecast, n_features_Y), name='future_inputs')

decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)
x = decoder_lstm(future_inputs, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)

# Create the model
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[past_inputs, future_inputs], outputs=output)
```

[The model looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq1FY.png)

I am afraid the problem is with this line:

```
future_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(forecast, n_features_Y), name='future_inputs')
```

The error I am getting is:

```
AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor("dense_23/Identity:0", shape=(None, 3, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Any ideas on how to correctly implement this?

Comment: Please specify your problem and post the errors if applicable.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. Edited mentioning the error.

Comment: I am also stuck in same kind of problem, can you please explain me what is difference between future_inputs and output.
If I want to train x1,x1....x60 and predict for x61..x64 what would be past_inputs future_inputs and output

Comment: Same issue here, i have nearly the same architecture